# Solutions Manual for Fundamentals of Domination in Graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Is there a solutions manual for:

> T.W. Haynes, S.T. Hedetniemi, and P.J. Slater (eds.), *Fundamentals of Domination in Graphs*, Marcel Dekker, Inc. New York, 1998.

If so, how do I obtain it?

Comment: It would be unusual if it did. Solutions manuals are usually only available for very elementary textbooks (Calc I, linear algebra, etc). If you have a question about one of the problems from that book, why not just post a question about it here?

Comment: I'm studying graph theory on my own and am really just looking for validation and intuition on the topics. I don't know why there would be a questions/problems sections if there was no provided means to validate answers. I'll post specific questions on this Exchange. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it's just the way it is I guess. I think the reality is that books such as that one have such a small target audience that it would not be worth anyone's time to publish a solutions manual; I would even hazard a guess that money would be lost. Besides, as you get better with math you develop the ability to know if your answer is correct without anyone's assistance. I look forward to your questions.

Comment: Have you found the solution manual or have you found other books on Domination in Graphs? I am trying to learn [domination by st-connectivity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821552/which-dominations-in-graphs-determined-by-st-connectivity).